# Why [^] is not a valid regular expression?

Tags: regex

In Oreilly's book 《Classic Shell Scripting》 section 3.2.2.4 "Anchoring text matches"
why the corresponding [^] is not a regular expression?

I dont't understand why it's not a regular expression? Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: Could you give a bit more context for those who don't have the book at hand? Do they have some kind of example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` signifies a character class.

Within the context of a character class, a `^` at the start signifies negation - that is, all the *following* characters should *not* be matched.

So, `[^]` is meaningless and so disallowed.

Comment: Yep, i think your idea  is more reasonable. 3KS

Comment: -1. It boils down to the syntax. If the syntax allows it and assigns it a meaning then it is valid. I think Gumbo's answer reflects this point.

Comment: +1 for being right.  Also, if you want to match ^, I believe you want \^

Answer (score 4):

It actually depends on the regular expression flavor whether `[^]` is valid.

In JavaScript, `[^]` is valid and denotes an arbitrary character. But most other flavors dictate that character class declarations cannot be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, since there is little context, but `[^]` is an incomplete character class, and hence not a regular expression. `[^a]` would be a regular expression:  Match a character that is not 'a'.

Comment: while the \v, \$. espically [$] is also valid, which is like [^] from the format style.

Comment: Not sure I followed your last comment @harris.